# Android: making search available throughout the whole application

Tags: android, search, manifest

Right now I'm adding

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
```

to every single `<activity>` in the AndroidManifest.xml, receive the `Intent` in each activity and forward the search string to one `singleTop` activity that actually performs the search (via HTTP/JSON) and displays the results in a list.

I'm wondering if there's a way how I can set-up the AndroidManifest.xml, so that search is activated in each activity within my application, but the search string will get forwarded from Android's search box directly to my `singleTop` SearchResults_Activity instead of going the way through validating events in each activity and then forwarding the search string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to that is actually available in the SearchManager documentation, in the [MetaData](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#SearchabilityMetadata) chapter.

> Activities which are part of a
>   searchable application, but don't
>   implement search itself, require a bit
>   of "glue" in order to cause them to
>   invoke search using your searchable
>   activity as their primary context. If
>   this is not provided, then searches
>   from these activities will use the
>   system default search context.

```
<application>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".MySearchActivity" />

    <!-- followed by activities, providers, etc... -->
</application>
```